# Can Apache-2.4 hand off a client connection to a PHP script that speaks WebSocket to the client?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, websocket

I have an Apache-2.4 web server.  It will execute PHP scripts if a client requests `https://my.domain.com/script-name.php`, and the output of the script shows up in the browser window.  (Or it can be retrieved as AJAX data by Javascript.)

I would like to have a PHP script started this way, but have it talk to Javascript code in the browser which has done:

```
ws = new WebSocket( 'https://my.domain.com/script-name.php' );
```

Is this something that can be managed from within the PHP script, or must I use something like `mod_proxy_wstunnel`?

(I believe the underlying question is, what communication channels are available to a PHP script started by Apache?  Does it have stdin/stdout as SSL sockets to/from the browser?  Or is it receiving buffered data from Apache, and writing output data back to a buffer that Apache will eventually send to the client?)

Answer (score 0):

After fooling around with this some more, I realized that it's not possible for Apache to `dup()` some file descriptors and `fork()/exec()` to run a CGI script -- even if it worked that way on a non-SSL connection, it wouldn't work on SSL at least because the child process does not know the SSL key or connection state and cannot transmit or receive data directly to the browser.  At least for SSL, Apache *must* forward the data back & forth.

As such, one of the `mod_proxy` solutions looks like the best bet here, too.  I was able to get `mod_proxy_wstunnel` running with very little pain, so that's how I'm going to move forward with this project.